# How do I create a batch file from Advantage SQL script?

Tags: batch-file, advantage-database-server

I have created sql script using SQL Utility within Advantage Data Architect of Sybase. The script is saved on my workstation. Now, how do I create a batch file that would run the script from desktop?

I found this command line online, but it doesn't seem to be working:

```
@echo on

isql -U "username" -P "password" -S "servername" -D "database" -i "path"

@echo off
```

I am new to Advantage SQL, trying to learn as much as I can.

Thanks.

Comment: What version of ADS are you using? There's no way to run SQL from a command line until the most recent version (11).

Comment: Thanks Ken, I am using version 11.10.0.10. Can you guide me how to run sql from command line with version 11?

Comment: Done. FYI, iSQL is for a specific DBMS (SQL Server, IIRC). Each DBMS has it's own utility if one is available.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use [adssqlcmd.exe](http://devzone.advantagedatabase.com/dz/webhelp/Advantage11.1/index.html?master_sql_command_line_utility_overview.htm), passing the connection and script name as [command-line parameters](http://devzone.advantagedatabase.com/dz/webhelp/Advantage11.1/index.html?master_sql_command_line_switches.htm). There is an example of doing so on that second page:

```
rem Using the connection path option, and process the script files 
rem after making the connection.
rem The program will terminate after processing all files
asqlcmd.exe -S ALS:d:\mydata\main.add -U user1 -P sample -i myscript.sql
```

There's a [list of supported commands](http://devzone.advantagedatabase.com/dz/webhelp/Advantage11.1/index.html?master_sql_command_line_supported_commands.htm) that outline what you can and can't do in the script as well.

Also note that adssqlcmd.exe is a feature added in ADS v11, and is not available to earlier versions of ADS.